# How to set a large constant with bitwise operation on ULong?

Tags: vb.net, bit-manipulation

This works nicely:

```
Public Const test As ULong = 1 << 30
```

This doesn't work nicely:

```
Public Const test As ULong = 1 << 31
```

It creates this error:

> Constant expression not representable in type 'ULong'

How do I make it work?

This does work:

```
Public Const test As Long = 1 << 31
```

But I have to use **ULong**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Public Const test As ULong = 1UL << 31
```

You need to explicitly tell the compiler you are doing the operation on a `ULong`.

The C# equivalent works:

```
public const ulong test  = 1UL << 31;
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot shift `1 << 31` with a Long datatype, so you get this error.

However, this is because `1`, as an integer literal, is treated as an Int32, which is the default integer literal.

You should work around this by defining this as:

```
Public Const test As ULong = 1UL << 30
Public Const test2 As ULong = 1UL << 31
```

The UL flag says to make the 1 an unsigned long.  [See Type characters for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: @Fredou: I go for quality, not speed.  Being first shouldn't make something the answer - it should be about being correct, and explaining the issue well...  Read the FAQ - it suggests waiting a few hours before marking an answer, since you should pick the "best" answer, not the fastest answer.

Comment: @Reed, for me, in this case, both answer are equal since both give the **UL** keyword and the same explanation which I had to explicitly say: this number is a ULong, not something else.

Comment: @Fredou: Oh, that's great.  I'm not saying to switch - just saying "faster isn't better"...